# show a holomorphic function f is harmonic.

Tags: complex-analysis

$$f(x+iy)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y) :  x,y \in R $$

$$\triangle(u)=\triangle(v)=0$$

Is there a very elegant and easy to understand proof to this?

Or do i have to derive it 2 times to show it works?

I really want an insight to this and why is it so usefull?

Comment: Use Cauchy-Riemann equations

Comment: You could prove that the real and imaginary parts of $f$ both have the mean value property, which implies that they are harmonic. This doesn't require any differentiation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can show that if $f = u + iv$ is holomorphic in a region $G$ then $u$ and $v$ are harmonic in $G$.

**Proof**: First we invoke the fact that $f$ is infinitely differentiable, and hence so are $u$ and $v$. In particular, $u$ and $v$ have continuous second partials. Now use the fact that $u$ and $v$ must satisfy the Cauchy–Riemann equations:

$u_{x} = v_{y}$ and $u_{y} = −v_{x}$  in $G$, hence

$u_{xx} +u_{yy} =(u_{x})_{x} +(u_{y})_{y} =(v_{y})_{x} +(−v_{x})_{y} =v_{yx} −v_{xy} =0$
in $G$.
$\square$

Note that in the last step we used the fact that $v$ has continuous second partials.
Hope this was what you were looking for!

Comment: thanks for the answer, if you may consider an edit that i made to the problem, does it change your proof? just curious.

Comment: The proof involving the Laplace operator (or, more precisely, that $v$ or $u$ satisfies the Laplace equation) is exactly analogous to the proof I provided.